# Self-join using multiple conditions

Tags: sql

Identify the purchase details of books, where the book is purchased on the same date, exactly on the date Anne has purchased the book. Write a SQL query to display customer’s name and title of the book for the identified purchase details. Do NOT display details of Anne in the query result.

There are these 3 tables for these requirements:

**Book**:

```
('B101', 'Science Revolution', 'Journal')
('B102', 'Brain Teasers', 'Aptitude')
('B103', 'India Today', 'Magazine')
('B104', 'Tech World', 'Journal')
('B105', 'Bizz world', 'Magazine')
```

**Customer**

```
('C101', 'Jack')
('C102', 'Anne')
('C103', 'Jane')
('C104', 'Maria')
```

**Purchase**:

```
('P201', 'C101', 'B102', '12-Dec-19')
('P202', 'C102', 'B103', '25-Nov-19')
('P203', 'C103', 'B104', '12-Dec-19')
('P204', 'C104', 'B105', '25-Nov-19') 
('P205', 'C101', 'B101', '11-Dec-19')
('P206', 'C101', 'B106', '12-Dec-19')
```

I used the following logic for the above requirement

```
select 
    b.bookname, c.custname 
from 
    customer c 
join 
    purchase p on c.custid > p.custid 
join 
    purchase p1 on p.custid > p1.custid 
                and p.purchasedate = p1.purchasedate 
join 
    book b on b.bookid = p1.bookid 
group by 
    b.bookname, c.custname;
```

Can anyone provide correct solution? Only 'Maria' 'Bizz world' has to appear in the result.

Comment: There are references to Anne in the problem description. I can see no reference to Anne in the query. Why then do you think it can be a correct solution to the problem?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result. (Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.)

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no set functions are involved? Are you simply trying to do SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: can someone provide the answer?

Comment: Your join conditions don't make sense. You're joining customers to purchases not made by them.

Comment: what is the solution for the problem? expected result is 'Maria' 'Bizz world'

Comment: Hi - especially for homework questions, no-one is just going to give you the answer, if that's what you are expecting? Instead, as they have done in the various comments, they will help you to be able to solve the problem yourself. If you are just given the answer then you won't learn anything. There are basically 2 steps you need to work through: 1) How do you identify when Anne purchased a book? 2) Using the date from step 1, how do you identify any other purchases made on this date, excluding Anne's?

Comment: Why is the expected result 'Maria' 'Bizz world'? Anne didn't buy that book that day, but another one. The request is "where the book is purchased on the same date, exactly on the date Anne has purchased the book". For the data provided, the expected result would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

> ```
> --
> -- what did Anne purchase? 
> --
> select c.custname, p.*
> from purchase as p
> JOIN customer AS c
>   ON c.custid = p.custid
> WHERE c.custname = 'Anne';
> ```
>
> ```
> custname | purchaseid | custid | bookid | purchasedate
> :------- | :--------- | :----- | :----- | :-----------
> Anne     | P202       | C102   | B103   | 25-Nov-19
> ```

**Step 2**

> ```
> --
> -- Any purchases on the same dates as Anna by other people?
> --
> select p2.*
> from purchase as p1
> join customer as c1 
>   on c1.custid = p1.custid
> JOIN purchase AS p2
>   ON p2.purchasedate = p1.purchasedate  -- same date
>  AND p2.custid != p1.custid -- different customer
> where c1.custname = 'Anne';
> ```
>
> ```
> purchaseid | custid | bookid | purchasedate
> :--------- | :----- | :----- | :-----------
> P204       | C104   | B105   | 25-Nov-19
> ```

**Step 3**

> ```
> --
> -- Now get the names from those id's
> --
> select c2.custname, b2.bookname
> from purchase as p1
> join customer as c1 
>   on c1.custid = p1.custid
> join purchase as p2
>   on p2.purchasedate = p1.purchasedate
>  and p2.custid != p1.custid
> JOIN customer AS c2
>   ON c2.custid = p2.custid
> JOIN book AS b2
>   ON b2.bookid = p2.bookid
> where c1.custname = 'Anne'
> ```
>
> ```
> custname | bookname  
> :------- | :---------
> Maria    | Bizz world
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7d44f96537b94021f2a4c6178b259249)*

Comment: thank you for the response!! but did'nt understand why you joined c2.custid=p2.custid

Comment: How else can you get the name of  'C104'?

Answer (score 0):

In similar construct as LukStorms provided,  first, lets start with how to get the date that Anne purchased the book.  That is the first and foremost requirement for your query.  I like to show indentation of the queries how table A gets to B gets to C, etc.

You already had many joins, I am just showing the first part.  Get the who, and the date of their purchase.  In this case, I am also getting the customer's ID so I know which ID to EXCLUDE from the final answer. Dont rely on knowing their customer ID and knowing you want purchases with the ID greater than the person.  What if you have 5000 people, and Anne happened to be person 2789.  Doing greater than would fail on any that also purchsed same date but fail on customer ID.

```
select
        p.custid,
        p.purchaseDate
    from
        customer c
            join purchase p
                on c.custid = p.custid
    where
        c.custname = 'Anne'
```

So from here, this can be the FIRST alias of the final select because the basis was to have the DATE of the purchase, but also now we KNOW the WHO we DONT want in the result.

```
select
        AnnePurchase.purchaseDate,
        c2.custname,
        b.bookName
    from
        (select
                p.custid,
                p.purchaseDate
            from
                customer c
                    join purchase p
                        on c.custid = p.custid
            where
                c.custname = 'Anne' ) AnnePurchase
            JOIN purchase p2
                -- first part, join to purchase on same date as Ann purchased her book
                on AnnePurchase.purchaseDate = p2.purchaseDate
                -- but now, get anyone who's customer ID is NOT the same as Anne.
                AND NOT AnnePurchase.custID = p2.custID
                -- now from the 2nd purchase table we can join to the customer and book 
                -- table to get whatever other parts you want
                JOIN customer c2
                    on p2.custid = c2.custid
                JOIN book b
                    on p2.bookid = b.bookid
```

Notice the in-line comments via -- that show WHY I am doing the join.  The AnnePurchase is the primary basis.  The join to Purchase (alias p2) is to get based on the same date and NOT the same customer ID as Anne.

From that, its a simple join from the P2 alias back to the customer and book tables.  I personally have the indentation of the joins for `customer c2` and `book b` indented under the purchase p2 because THAT is the basis of their relationship.